# Inserting or Updating multiple values into a MySQL table using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, upsert

I have a table that has a composite primary key of (room_id, x_coord, and y_coord) and another column called card_id. I am trying to insert several records into a mysql database. I am using the mysql library as well as the express library for node.js.

If the record does not exist I would like to insert a new record consisting of room_id, x_coord, y_coord, and card_id.

On the other hand, if the record does exist, I would like to update the current record to the new card_id.

Here is a copy of my current code:

```
//previously defined: room_id, x, y, and cards[]

var i = 0;
var db_values = [];
for (var row = 0; row < y; row++){
    for (var col = 0; col < x; col++){
        card = cards[i];
        //The following line may have a problem?
        db_values.push([room_id, col, row, card['id'], card['id']]);

        i++;
    }
}


sql = "insert into user_card(room_id, x_coord, y_coord, card_id) values ? on duplicate key update card_id = values(?)";
//The following line may have a problem?
db_connection.query(sql, [db_values], function (err, result){
    if (err){
        console.log("Upsert  DB ERROR: " + err);
        return;
    }

});
```

I have tried various combinations of code each yielding different errors. The one above yields the following error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '?)' at line 1

What am I doing wrong here and what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe the number of question marks in your prepared statement should match the length of your argument list (db_values Array).
Second, you don't want parentheses around the value in your update clause. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Maybe a statement more like this would work:

```
insert into user_card(room_id, x_coord, y_coord, card_id)
values (?, ?, ?, ?)
on duplicate key update card_id=?
```

EDIT: 
That query would only work for a single card. You probably want to create an insert statement for each card, which requires that you build the query inside of a loop. Also, it looks like `db_values` would be an Array of Arrays and you're passing it to the db_connection.query method with another Array.  I imagine that method probably only wants a single Array of Strings.

Comment: Along with the modified query, the db_values should not be passed as array.   Pass the db_values as it is..

Comment: @srivelayutharaja and Jim. Thank you for trying to help. However, I have solved the answer. Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to change the last `?` to the column name that you want inserted.

So change this line:

```
sql = "insert into user_card(room_id, x_coord, y_coord, card_id)
        values ? on duplicate key update card_id = values(?)";
```

To this line:

```
sql = "insert into user_card(room_id, x_coord, y_coord, card_id)
        values ? on duplicate key update card_id = values(card_id)";
```

It is also important to make sure that you surround `[db_values]` with brackets in your query in the following line:

```
db_connection.query(sql, [db_values], function (err, result){
```

That was one area that was also giving me trouble as I was originally trying it without the brackets.